# How To Install Pytesseract in windows 8.1(win64) (visual studio 2012+python+anaconda)

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-2012, tesseract, pytesser

```
from PIL import Image
from tesseract import image_to_string

print image_to_string(Image.open('C:\Users/Uzel/Desktop/pythonfoto/denklem.png'))
print image_to_string(Image.open('C:\Users/Uzel/Desktop/pythonfoto/denklem.png'), lang='eng')
```

I use this code after installing tesseract orc.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Uzel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\module3.py", line 28, in 
    from tesseract import image_to_string
ImportError: cannot import name image_to_string

I have this error. I tried pytesseract but I can not manage. Can we solve this problem. How? thank you.

Comment: Change `C:\Users/Uzel/Desktop/pythonfoto/denklem.png` to `C:/Users/Uzel/Desktop/pythonfoto/denklem.png`.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work again. I think tesseract don't have image_to_string. And I can not install pytesseract if I install it can be.

Comment: Can you elaborate? You did make the change on the image path and it did work for once?

Comment: yes I changed and compiled but did not work. Do you use pytesseract ? Can you advice for me? How can I download ?

Comment: I'm using `pytesseract`. You may see my Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sample code with `pytesseract`.

```
import pytesseract 
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files/Tesseract 4.0.0/tesseract.exe"
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("./imagesStackoverflow/text.png"),
                                  lang="eng",boxes=False,config="--psm 3 --eom 3"))
```

The `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd` is to specific the EXE path explicitly in case the path hasn't been properly set up in Windows environment.

You need to have Tesseract installed in Windows and pytesseract installed with Python.

Hope this help.